# Group structure on an interval in Z[1/p]

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

Is there any natural group structure on the set $I_p = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p] \mid |x| < p/2\}$?

Comment: This is a really strange question without any motivation.  What could "natural" possibly mean?

Answer (score 2):

This set doesn't have a subgroup structure as a subset of the reals, but if p is an odd prime, you can certainly lift the additive group law on Q<sub>p</sub>/pZ<sub>p</sub> to this set.  An alternative way to look at it that works for arbitrary odd numbers p is to lift the p-power roots of unity in the complex numbers by the map x -> e<sup>2 pi ix/p</sup>.

If p is even, you probably have to make more choices.